# How does Google Inbox show a snackbar covering the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-snackbar, snackbar

[image]

How does Google Inbox show the snackbar over (covering, layering) the keyboard? This is not the default behaviour, which I've tested with a basic coordinator layout, the keyboard open and a snackbar: the default behaviour is showing the snackbar **behind** the keyboard. There are many answers on SO to the question: *'How do I show the snackbar **above** the keyboard'*, but I haven't found how to reproduce Google's own Inbox app's snackbar behaviour.

Can you show me how to achieve this?

Comment: I tried setting the snackbar's view's elevation, which by default is 6, to large numbers, but this doesn't help. I tried elevations up to 5000!

Comment: I would assume that they have to be using an overlay window (e.g., `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` pre-8.0, `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` on 8.0+). I don't use Google Inbox so I cannot test this scenario. But, if Inbox does not have this behavior on 8.0+, but does on 7.1 and older, then it's very likely to be an overlay, because [overlays cannot overlay the IME on 8.0+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#cwt).

Comment: `elevations` only affects inside your application layout. I think there may be some tricks with creating Snakebar with different context.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's present both on Android 7.1 (screenshot in question) and 8.0 (my current phone).

Comment: "Very few apps should use this permission; these [overlay] windows are intended for system-level interaction with the user." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW). My use case doesn't legitimise the use of this permission: I want to give feedback to my users while the snackbar is open and I support tiny screens where there is no room for a snackbar above the keyboard. Furthermore, I saw this snackbar behaviour in Google Inbox, so I figured that would be a good solution for me. No luck yet, so it seems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inbox doesn't use the standard Snackbar nor uses an overlay window, it uses a custom view. I decompiled the APK to verify how they achieve this effect and I tried to reproduce a minimal example.

First of all create a new layout *custom_snackbar.xml*:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#323232"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Marked done"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="undo"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#a1c2fa"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create these methods to show and dismiss the custom Snackbar:

```
private View customSnackbar;

private void showCustomSnackbar(final Context context) {
    customSnackbar = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_snackbar, null, false);
    customSnackbar.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //action implementation
        }
    });

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    lp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
    customSnackbar.setLayoutParams(lp);

    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    if (windowManager != null) {
        windowManager.addView(customSnackbar, customSnackbar.getLayoutParams());

        Point m = new Point();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(m);
        int childMeasureSpecWidth = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(m.x, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 0, lp.width);
        int childMeasureSpecHeight = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(m.y, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 0, lp.height);
        customSnackbar.measure(childMeasureSpecWidth, childMeasureSpecHeight);

        customSnackbar.setTranslationY(customSnackbar.getMeasuredHeight());
        customSnackbar.animate()
                .setDuration(300)
                .translationX(0.0f)
                .translationY(0.0f);
    }
}

private void dismissCustomSnackbar(final Context context) {
    customSnackbar.animate()
            .setDuration(300)
            .translationX(0.0f)
            .translationY(customSnackbar.getMeasuredHeight())
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                    if (windowManager != null) {
                        windowManager.removeView(customSnackbar);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

This is the result obtained:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I do not mess with `WindowManager` much... but why is this able to appear over the IME? I thought the changes in Android 8.0 regarding `WindowManager`-added windows was supposed to prevent this sort of thing. Regardless, nice work!

Comment: The Android 8.0 limitations seems to apply only to the type `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`. In this example the view has the default type `TYPE_APPLICATION`.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome. I will try this later in my apps and report here if any quirks or edge cases occur. I also guess it would be possible to build a `Snackbar` in the regular way and then, if the keyboard is open, instead of displaying it regularly, using this method to display it in front of the keyboard. This way this custom snackbar behaviour could be adapted to different keyboard situations.