# Snackbar android apear behind dialog popup

Tags: java, android, xml, snackbar

I have one Activity that has one popup `Dialog` inside it. Inside the popup Activity, I have `ImageButton` to show `SnackBar` . The problem is, the `SnackBar` is showing in the activity not in the popup `Dialog`.

Im using FlashBar from this
https://github.com/aritraroy/Flashbar

It is possible to show the `FLashBar` above the popup dialog?

MyPopup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="i"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="showInfoPengumuman"
        android:background="@drawable/circlebackground"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

myActivity.java

```
public void showPopupPengumuman(View v){
TextView txtInfo = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);

txtInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showInfoPengumuman();
    }
});
myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
myDialog.show();

    };

  private Flashbar primaryActionListener() {
        return new Flashbar.Builder(this)
                .gravity(Flashbar.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                .title("Tata Cara Upload Pengumuman")
                .showIcon()
                .backgroundColorRes(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                .enterAnimation(FlashAnim.with(this)
                        .animateBar()
                        .duration(750)
                        .alpha()
                        .overshoot())
                .exitAnimation(FlashAnim.with(this)
                        .animateBar()
                        .duration(400)
                        .accelerateDecelerate())
                .message("Lengkapi Deskripsi -> Tambah -> Validasi Deskripsi -> Publish")
                .primaryActionText("DISMISS")
                .primaryActionTapListener(new Flashbar.OnActionTapListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActionTapped(@NotNull Flashbar bar) {
                        bar.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    private void showInfoPengumuman(){
        flashbar = primaryActionListener();
        flashbar.show();
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the source code, no, you can't do that, unless you modify that library's code. It's written to attach to an `Activity` specifically, and `Dialog`s will always show above an `Activity`'s content.

Comment: How if I'm change it to the default snackbar?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: How to achieve it using default snackbar?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to show inside the `Dialog`? If so, then you'll need to pass a `View` that's in the `Dialog` as the first argument in `Snackbar.make()`.

Comment: I mean in front of dialog

Comment: You can't really do that, with a normal setup. `Dialog`s always show above an `Activity`'s content. You'd have to do something like is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760678/how-does-google-inbox-show-a-snackbar-covering-the-keyboard.