# Are there any possible ways on the android native to display some sort of Dialog or BottomSheetDialog overlap to the soft keyboard

Tags: android, dialog, android-view, android-softkeyboard, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm just curious after using the Facebook application (my currently version is v249.0) for a while, On the comment part that you can have a comment which can be a text or some sort of image (image, sticker or GIF). My curiosity is here... If you choose to attach an image, the `BottomSheetDialog` will be prompted and overlap the soft keyboard by the same width/height as an images shown below...

**1:Only the keyboard is displayed**

[image: Image#1 - Only the keyboard is displayed]

**2.Dialog is show and replace its view overlap to the soft keyboard**

[image: Image#2 - Dialog is show and replace its view overlap to the soft keyboard]

What are the concepts or techniques that can be used to achieve this?

Comment: To display over the keyboard, you'll have to add a `View` directly to `WindowManager`; something like is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613898).

Comment: @MikeM. Thank for your precious response, This may be the most possible way I'm looking for. I will give a try...